# Vue Cli and Vue.js v3 script setup

Tags: vuejs3, eslintrc, vue-cli-4

I am already successfully using Vue.js v3 by creating a project with Vue CLI or with Vite.
Now I need to have just single .vue files that I can run and build individually.
I read this is possible just by using "vue serve myfile.vue" and "vue build myfile.vue", but unfortunately I am having some trouble.
I have the last vue-cli version installed. Sure enough if I launch in the command line "vue --version" I get "@vue/cli 4.5.14".
Then, in a directory I created a very simple .vue file with the following code:

```
    <template>
        <h1>The count is 1</h1>
    </template>
```

If I run "vue serve myfile.vue", everything works fine, then I am happy to continue and make some more interesting things.
Now I add a script setup section to the file:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

const count = ref(0);
</script>

<template>
    <h1>The count is {{ count }}</h1>
</template>
```

Now if I relaunch "vue serve myfile.vue", I get the following error:
4:7  error  'count' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

Ok, I am a newbie about ESLint, so I started to search for something on the internet and I found that I must use a rule that can solve this problem, and the rule is "vue/script-setup-uses-vars".
Then I added a new file .eslintrc.json in the root path:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "vue"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "vue/no-unused-vars": "warn",
        "vue/script-setup-uses-vars": "warn"
    }
}
```

I try again but I get this warning: " 1:1  warning  Definition for rule 'vue/script-setup-uses-vars' was not found vue/script-setup-uses-vars".
Then I guess it is not working...
Nonetheless, if I run again "vue serve myfile.vue", the local server gets created but at the same time I get a different warning:

```
 warning  in ./myfile.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js&

"export 'ref' was not found in 'vue'
```

And here I start to not understand.
Is my .eslintrc.json file wrong? Why "ref" is not found from "vue"?
I searched a lot on the internet but I can't find anything helpful.
Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work?
Thanks!